# pickatime.js opening when double/triple clicked on render event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a project using pickatime.js and pickadate.js. I'm facing an issue where the time picker appears if I double or triple click on the element meant to only render it (not open it) but a single click doesn't replicate the error. Here's sample code which replicates the issue.

As you can see I have attempted to use `stopImmediatePropagation` with no luck.

This seems to be a problem with pickatime.js - how can I prevent this?

Thanks.

```js
 $(".render-time-picker").dblclick(function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });


$(".render-time-picker").click(function (e) {

        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        returnTimePicker.render();
            
    });

    $(".return-time-picker").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        returnTimePicker.open();
    });

    //Start Return Time
    let $returnTimePicker = $('#return-time').pickatime({
        clear: "",
    onRender: function() {
            console.log ("Rendered!")
        },
        onStart: function() {
            this.set('select', [12, 0]); // Sets the default selected time to noon
        },
    });
    let returnTimePicker = $returnTimePicker.pickatime('picker');
    //End Return Time
```

```html
<button class="render-time-picker p-6 border border-red-400">Render time picker (Double/Triple Click for Acccidental Renter / Single Click for Expected Result)</button>

<button class="return-time-picker p-6 border border-green-400">
    Set Return Time (Opens Picker)
</button>

<input type="text" name="return-time" id="return-time" class="border border-gray-200">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.css" id="theme_base">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.date.css" id="theme_date">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/themes/default.time.css" id="theme_time">

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.js"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.date.js"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.time.js"></script>
<script src="https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/legacy.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the issue was with these lines of code in `picker.time.js`

```
animations = function( $el, state ) {
  vendors( 'transform' ).map(function( prop ) {
      $el.css( prop, state )
  })
  vendors( 'transition' ).map(function( prop ) {
      $el.css( prop, state )
  })
}
```

By removing `$el.css( prop, state )` the behavior stopped and I didn't notice any loss in functionality. It looks like a bug that the developer never fixed, and the project seems to have been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

looks like theres a double render on the page also.
witha plugin like this I might do something like set a flag onRender that prevents rendering for happening again until a flag has changed.

Something like

```
const isRendered = false;

$(".render-time-picker").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (!isRendered) { returnTimePicker.render(); }
   
});

let $returnTimePicker = $('#return-time').pickatime({
    clear: "",
    onRender: function() {
        isRendered = true
        console.log ("Rendered!")
        // idk maybe setTimeout or whenever you think you might want to allow re-rendnering
    },
    onStart: function() {
        this.set('select', [12, 0]);
    },
});
```

disclaimer: this is more of a workaround.

edit: looks like it's designed to open if it's rendered already, so the workaround might be suitable

https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/vendor/pickadate/lib/picker.js

```
        /**
         * Render a new picker
         */
        render: function( entireComponent ) {

            // Insert a new component holder in the root or box.
            if ( entireComponent ) {
                P.$holder = $( createWrappedComponent() )
                prepareElementHolder()
                P.$root.html( P.$holder )
            }
            else P.$root.find( '.' + CLASSES.box ).html( P.component.nodes( STATE.open ) )

            // Trigger the queued “render” events.
            return P.trigger( 'render' )
        }, //render
```

Comment: The issue there is I need to render it numerous times (when the user changes a setting for example).

Comment: that where I'd recommend something like a setTimeout that turns the isRendered flag back to false after a couple milliseconds, or prehaps in one of the selection events like "onSet", the library code is basically saying there if the component exists in the dom then it is rendered and just display the dialog

Comment: this shouldn't stop render on any other events, only preventing that specific button click

Comment: I just tried it, at 1000ms and even as high as 5000ms, it doesn't really work reliably. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you notice with the pickadate.js it isn't occurring when you click "Add stuff". But with pickatime.js it is: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-render -- so it's not by design I don't think...

Comment: 1000 is probably way tooo high, it would be noticable to the user. try like 200ms and try the option of resetting the flag in one of the other callbacks which might be the more robust option. note the render method comes from that core lib both date a time use it. you're other other option is just to fork the library code itself an remove/modify the offending else statement.

Comment: at 200ms there was no noticeable difference.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you're describing might be due to the way event propagation and handling work. The click event might be triggering the default behavior of the time picker even though you're using stopImmediatePropagation().

Here's a suggestion to try resolving the issue:

```
$(".render-time-picker").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default click behavior
e.stopPropagation();
returnTimePicker.render(); // Render the time picker
});
```

Comment: Tried all that, no luck.